# R: calculate occurence of words from a list in data frame

Tags: r, aggregate, plyr

I have a data frame with `Category` and `pd`. I need to calculate how many times each meaningful word from all `pd` is seen in each `Category`. I'm stuck with the last step - summary. Ideally, ratio of that frequency to total length of `pd` by `Category` would be another X columns.

Example:

```
freq = structure(list(Category = c("C1", "C2"
), pd = c("96 oz, epsom salt 96 oz, epsom bath salt", 
          "17 x 24 in, bath mat")), .Names = c("Category", "pd"), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                -2L), class = "data.frame")

pool = sort(unique(gsub("[[:punct:]]|[0-9]","", unlist(strsplit(freq[,2]," ")))))
pool = pool[nchar(pool)>1]
```

`freq`:

```
    Category    pd
1   C1  96 oz, epsom salt 96 oz, epsom bath salt
2   C2  17 x 24 in, bath mat
```

`pool`:

```
[1] "bath"  "epsom" "in"    "mat"   "oz"    "salt"
```

Desired output:

```
pool C1freq C1ratio C2freq C2ratio
bath 1 1/7 1 1/3
epsom 2 2/7 0 0
in 0 0 1 1/3
mat 0 0 1 1/3
oz 2 2/7 0 0
salt 2 2/7 0 0
```

Where, e.g. `7` is the length of `C1[,2]` with numbers, punctuation removed (as in `pool` rules). `1/7` of course is not necessary in this form - here it is just to show the denominator length.

If possible, w/o `dplyr` or `qdap`. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could try

```
library(qdapTools)
library(stringr)
lst <- str_extract_all(freq$pd, '[A-Za-z]{2,}')
m1 <- t(mtabulate(lst))
m2 <-  prop.table(m1,2)
cbind(m1, m2)[,c(1,3,2,4)]
```

---

Or without the `qdapTools`,

```
 Un1 <- sort(unique(unlist(lst)))
 m1 <- do.call(cbind, lapply(lst, function(x)
            table(factor(x, levels=Un1))))
 colnames(m1) <- freq$Category
 cbind(m1, `colnames<-`(prop.table(m1,2), paste0(colnames(m1), 'Prop')))
```

Comment: Thank you @akrun. Is it possible to preserve names of original `freq` instead of generic `V1` in a simple manner?

Comment: @AlexeyFerapontov  Added the column names

Answer (score 1):

You can consider adapting your current approach in the following manner:

```
tab <- table(
  stack(
    setNames(
      lapply(strsplit(gsub("[[:punct:]]|[0-9]", "", freq$pd), "\\s+"), 
             function(x) x[nchar(x) > 1]), freq$Category)))
```

Notice here that I used `gsub` first, rather than after splitting. Then, I split on a space, and filtered the data in the same manner that you had filtered it. Finally, I used `setNames` so that I would be able to use `stack` to get a long `data.frame` that could be tabulated.

Once the data are tabulated, just use `prop.table` to get your desired output.

```
cbind(tab, prop.table(tab, 2))
#       C1 C2        C1        C2
# bath   1  1 0.1428571 0.3333333
# epsom  2  0 0.2857143 0.0000000
# in     0  1 0.0000000 0.3333333
# mat    0  1 0.0000000 0.3333333
# oz     2  0 0.2857143 0.0000000
# salt   2  0 0.2857143 0.0000000
```

Comment: Thank you! Not sure what I'm doing wrong, but I don't get fractions

Comment: @AlexeyFerapontov, you should be able to run this directly from your sample data. Did you do the `cbind` step at the end?

Comment: I did. I get 5 columns: 2 and 4, 3 and 5 are identical and are counts. In your example 3 and 5 are fractions. Did copy/paste

Comment: @AlexeyFerapontov, maybe there's something interfering in your work environment? See [here](http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=5VQf3rRe) for verification with this sample data.

Comment: Not sure. I opened new session. Still the same